# Excel vba list issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have created a Command Button on my work sheet with the following codes. My excel file has more than 80 sheets. Now the issue in this list appears partially due to a big list. (first 40 items only)

How can I divide this list into 2 or 3 vertical lists?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim myList As String
    Dim mySht

    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        myList = myList & i & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name & " " & vbCr
    Next i

    mySht = InputBox("Select Sheet to go to." & vbCr & myList)

    If mySht = "" Then
        'MsgBox "User pressed CANCEL or empty string is submitted"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not IsNumeric(mySht) Or mySht < 1 Or mySht > ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count Then
        MsgBox "Wrong input"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(CInt(mySht)).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "this list appears partially" -- what list?  Where?  Also, what do you mean by "divide this list into 2 or 3 vertical lists"?  Again, where?

Comment: If I click that command button, whole excel sheet list comes to screen with 1,2,...,n numbers. Eg. if I enter 2, second sheet activate. "this list appears partially" means I can not see whole sheets at a time. Please create command button on excel sheet with above codes and see. if it is more that 40 sheets, bottom sheets can not see. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand at all.

Comment: Thanks for your willingness to help me. Again I will try to explain my issue.

Comment: If you have a listbox or combobox, go to the control properties, and you will be able to increase the number of displayed lines.

Comment: I have excel file with 80 sheets. That is data base and first sheet names as "Menu". I have created a Command button to move easily. It works. But issue is, once I click this button, first 40 sheet names appears with numbering 1 - Sheet1, 2 - Sheet2, etc. there is an inbox. If I enter no.2 and click OK. Sheet2 active. Means I can see sheet2 things. But after first 40 sheets, I can not see others.

Comment: Do you mean the prompt in your inputbox is only showing a limited selection of your string myList? I would suggest making a userform with a Listbox listing the available sheets.

Comment: What code do you use to move between sheets?

Comment: It is not listbox or combobox. It is Command Button with VB programming codes as above.

Comment: Command button placed on the first excel sheet.

Comment: i'd use u userform with a listbox instead of inputbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a list and entering it in the prompt where there isn't enough space. I suggest creating a custom form with a listbox like so:

Go to the VBA screen

Insert Userform

Add a Listbox

Add a Command button

Enter this code in the Userform module

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim myStr As String
    myStr = Me.ListBox1
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(myStr).Activate
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Then have your command button open the userform

Comment: It works, thank you very much for your support, still one issue is there, how to set button on Menu sheet to get this userform

Comment: Assuming you haven't changed the name of the form, just enter Userform1.Show in the commandbutton code